# Bean and Autowiring

Tags: spring

So I have a bean definition for a class and an autowiring of the same class. Can you tell me if these are separate. I think they are, but it does not make sense with the rest of the code (I am following a tutorial).

```
@Bean
    public OAuth2RestTemplate googleOpenIdTemplate(final OAuth2ClientContext clientContext) {
        final OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(googleOpenId(), clientContext);
        return template;
    }


@Autowired
    private OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

The two snippets of code would created two different instances of the same class with DIFFERENT configurations, correct?

If I had

```
OAuth2RestTemplate instance = (OAuth2RestTemplate) context.getBean(googleOpenIdTemplate)
```

I would be retrieving a bean with the same configurations (singleton vs prototype) whereas in the first case, I would just get a bean of OAuth2RestTemplate without the same configurations.

Comment: "They are separate" - what do you mean by this? The `@Bean` part will register a bean of type OAuth2RestTemplate. The `@Autowired` will auto-wire this bean (assuming you only have 1 bean registered of type `OAuth2RestTemplate`)

Comment: I edited the code snippets and my question. Hope it helps.

Comment: @devang So then autowiring will create an instance of the type OAuth2RestTemplate with the same configurations as googleOpenIdTemplate() ? My understanding of autowiring is that it simply injects an instance of a class without the same configurations and using context.getBean() allows you to retrieve the a bean of the same configurations.

Comment: I seem to be misunderstanding something with beans and autowiring. I understand a bean to be an object that I can use. If I only have definition of a bean, autowiring a class of the same type that I used for the bean will give me the exact same type of bean?

Comment: `@Bean` will result into creation of a new bean. `@Autowired` and context.getBean will return the same bean that was created as part of `@Bean`

Comment: For more details -- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-getbean

Comment: Okay so then, I can understand Bean to be a certain way to cook meatloaf, and autowiring and context.getbean will allow me to get the certain recipe, although there are multiple ways to cook  a meatloaf as there are multiple ways to configure a class with different properties such as house vs apartment in a housing class?

Comment: Okay, I think I seem to understand. Simply put, I can have a Bean definition for Cars, specifically a red one. When I autowire and request the bean definition for Cars, I will get a red one back, not a black or white one. Now if I have two Bean definitions for Cars, I can get either in which case I specify which color I want.

Comment: Look at `@Qualifier` identifier. If you are registering multiple beans of the same type, then you give each bean a name using `@Qualifier` annotation. And when you autowire, if you need single bean of the multiple beans, you need to explicitly mention the bean you need. If you autowire a list, it will populate it with all beans of that type.

Comment: I see... So the bean is an instance of a class that is replicated throughout autowiring. This is how the benefit of being able to spread an instance shared throughout the application comes into play... I believe I saw {{name=nameofbean}} somewhere before. I will check out the @Qualifier.

Comment: `context.getBean(..)` and `@Autowired` are 2 different ways of doing the same thing, i.e. get the created bean. `@Autowired` is convenient over `context.getBean(..)` as it's less coding (you don't have to inject the context and then fetching the bean)